# CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation vs startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Tags: objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

I am working on a web application that enables users to login to the app, only if they're in certain specified regions. I called `locationManager startUpdatingLocation` at the beginning of my app to get the user's location and enables/disables logging in.

Once the user is logged on, I called

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

and logs the user out when the updated location is outside of the region. Would using the two methods clash in any way? (I'm testing the code on the simulator therefore the location is always the same).

Note: I'm not using `didEnterRegion` or `didExitRegion` because everything is handled by an existing Javascript code. I'm only sending in the user's current location.

Comment: They don't clash. I tested it. You can run both safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you need with the location after the user logs in. When you monitor for significant changes, your locationManager will only be notified on major changes. (e.g. New cell tower, change in wifi, other app calls location, etc). It won't be on a consistent basis. If all you care about is the user logging in, I would possibly do away with the significant monitoring all together. If you still need location, then be prepared to only get sporadic updates on the location.

Comment: I started with `startUpdatingLocation` because when I tried using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` at the start of the application, it wasn't sending the current location to my application. After the user logs in, I don't really use the location unless the user exits the area where he's allowed to be logged in, therefore I thought monitoring significant would work. I haven't tested on an actual device yet (and move around enough to have monitoring significant to notify me of anything) because I'm still waiting for Apple to approve me as a paying iOS Developer.

Comment: Generally if you are active in your app, you would actively monitor location. Monitoring significant location is when location updates aren't needed as often. Like in the background. This helps with battery life.

Comment: If you only need to monitor a specific area, I would suggest the region monitoring methods. I am currently using them and they work pretty great. Look into -startMonitoringForRegion, you should find what you need.

Comment: I did look into region monitoring, however I already have an existing code that checks for regions if I pass it the current location. I prefer location updates instead of region monitoring so it's more consistent to other platforms. Thanks!